# anaconda not able open spyder and anaconda environment not getting activated

Tags: anaconda, conda

please help on this uninstalled it and reinstalled it again but still not working. even downgraded to a previous working version

```
Invoke-Expression : At line:1 char:750
+ ... nstall\bin;"C:\Users\avkgu\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;";C:\P
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'C:\Users\avkgu\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps' in expression or statement.
At D:\Anaconda3\shell\condabin\Conda.psm1:101 char:9
+         Invoke-Expression -Command $activateCommand;
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Invoke-Expression], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeExpressionCommand 


PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> conda info

     active environment : None
       user config file : C:\Users\avkgu\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\avkgu\.condarc
          conda version : 4.7.10
    conda-build version : 3.18.8
         python version : 3.7.3.final.0
       virtual packages :
       base environment : D:\Anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : D:\Anaconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\avkgu\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\avkgu\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : D:\Anaconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\avkgu\.conda\envs
                          C:\Users\avkgu\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.7.10 requests/2.22.0 CPython/3.7.3 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.18362
          administrator : True
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

not able to activate conda

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> conda env list
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  D:\Anaconda3
```

even activating is not working

Comment: Where does that error come from?

Comment: i used anaconda powershell prompt to boot it where i got this error

Comment: No solution for that? I'm struggling to solve it.